# Using “could” and “should” in conditionals

Tags: word-choice, conditionals

Can I use “could” and “should” in the sentences below?

1. If Aliens attacked us tonight, we could hide underground.
2. If my father were still alive, we could ask him for some advice.
3. If he were here, I should beat him up.
4. If China invaded tomorrow, I should fight back to protect my family.

Answer (score 1):

"Could" can be used as a past tense or *irrealis* modal, so 1 and 2 are fine.

"Should" is a present and *realis* modal only, so 3 and 4 are incorrect

Answer (score 0):

*"If Aliens attacked us tonight, we could hide underground."* - It is possible to hide.

*"If Aliens attacked us tonight, we should hide underground."* - It is possible to hide and that is what you should do.

*"If my father were still alive, we could ask him for some advice."* - if he were alive it would have been possible to ask.

*"If my father were still alive, we should ask him for some advice."* - this does not make sense.

*"If he were here, I should beat him up."* - ambiguous. It could mean that you ought to beat him up, or it could simply mean that would beat him up.

*"If China invaded tomorrow, I should fight back to protect my family."* - ambiguous as above.

*"If China invaded tomorrow, I could fight back to protect my family."* - if it happened it would be possible for you to fight.

Comment: The convention of using _shall_ and _should_ for first-person forms is not very widespread now. Especially _should_: if you use _I should_ where you would use _he would_ people wll be often unsure whether you intend the "obligation" sense of "should".

Comment: I think the meaning of advice and obligations of could and should is not commonly used in type 2 condition. When could and should are used, the are usually interpreted as “possible to”

Answer (score 0):

*Should X* means X is correct (but not necessarily true/exists).

*Could X* means X is able to happen or be performed.

Does the result of X happening make it correct or right for you to do Y?

Then you can say *If X, I should Y*.

Does the result of X happening enables you to be able to do something Y?

Then you can say you can say, *If X, I could Y.*

---

> If Aliens attacked us tonight, we could hide underground.

You can hide underground without aliens attacking, so "aliens attacking" does not make "hiding underground" able to happen.  "Hiding underground" is the correct thing to do if aliens attack.  Therefore, *should*.

> If my father were still alive, we could ask him for some advice.

"Being alive" makes "being asked for advice" able to happen.  But the mere fact of your father being alive probably doesn't in itself make asking him for advice the correct thing to do.  Therefore, *could*.

> If he were here, I should beat him up.

Do you really consider it correct to beat people up just because they are here?  Probably not.  But "being here" does enable "getting beaten up" unless you like punching thin air or have a remote method.  Therefore, *could*.

> If China invaded tomorrow, I should fight back to protect my family.

Fighting back is the correct thing to do when you are invaded.

Does "invaded tomorrow" specifically make "fighting back" able to happen?  Depends on precisely what is meant by "fighting back" - "fighting back" means to defend against an initiating attacker.

Therefore, *could* or *should* are valid here depending on what you want to say.